How to get emailed about future Firebase Cloud Messaging updates
On Jun 20, 2023, the below email was sent by firebase-noreply@google.com. I received this email, but some coworkers did not.
What criteria was used to determine who got this email? How can I ensure a certain email address/google iam address will get future updates like this one?

Subject: [Action Required] Update your apps to the latest Firebase Cloud Messaging APIs and SDKs


Body: ... We’re writing to let you know that starting June 20, 2024 the legacy Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) APIs will be discontinued...


Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

Go to your firebase console -> your project -> Click on the notification Icon -> Click on the gear icon to open notification settings make sure you have enabled email notification for all sections.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer support question.


Hi First of all I'm no official or have any sort of insider information (as customer support would have and stuff.), I'm a user just like you. So any information I provide is from my experience or from online sources that may or may not be credible.
The advise would be to seek this information from the relevant personal. (Probably not on this community.)

Now that that's out of the way, lets focus on the question.

I received this email, but some coworkers did not.

Of what I know about this is that Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) updates are typically not sent via email, and the email you received in June 2023 seems to be an exception (or time limited).
And it could've been subjected to Targeted Mailing or there could've been some Subscription Issue


What criteria was used to determine who got this email?

What I know is that Google typically sends these types of notifications to (Sometimes):

Google Cloud project owners and editors
Users who have interacted with FCM in the Google Cloud Console or Firebase Console
Developers who have actively used FCM APIs or SDKs

I know this doesn't exactly answer the intent behind this question, but as I've mentioned before starting the answer, that's all that I can tell.

Next up

How can I ensure a certain email address/google iam address will get future updates like this one?

From what I could understand of the question to increase the likelihood of receiving such important updates you can try the following:

Ensure you and your colleagues have appropriate roles (owner, editor, or viewer) on the Firebase or Google Cloud projects using FCM.

In your firebase and cloud console settings check the "Notifications" tab and ensure email notifications are enabled

Ensure you're subscribed to product updates and newsletters

Follow Firebase on Twitter (@firebase) and other social media

Check the Firebase blog (firebase blog)

If you use the Firebase CLI, ensure it's up to date as it sometimes provides notifications



Good Luck!

To get updates on firebase updating a SDK you should subscribe to their News and Events newsletter. To access the news and events. Use the following link.
https://console.firebase.google.com/subscriptions/overview
Make sure you have turned and News and Updates to receive notifications on SDK and other product updates from Firebase.
Hope this helps!

Please refer to the documentation: Receive Firebase alerts.
As one can see, the one user with role "Owner" gets all the alerts by default, otherwise this requires to have permission firebase.projects.update assigned. If you want others to also get these alerts, you have to grant them this permission. As explained in the other one answer, these alerts would need be enabled - but the permission ultimately dictates, who will receive them.
